# How do I get a ball to fall randomly in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

With full compliments, may I start by declaring that I am new to iPhone programming. Thus I will like to ask for help on the solution on how to implement an animation where "a" ball falls randomly from the top of the iPhone screen. The ball's attribute is such that it has different sizes, speed and can bounce too i.e there is collision also involved.

I am trying to use just an image of the ball and I added the ball image through Interface Builder(IB) and connected the UIImageView to files owner in IB and I have been trying without success to access the image programatically by adding the IBOutlet keyword to the .h file(please see the .h and .m code below).
 When I run the code all I get is the image appearing and instantly disappearing. how do I get this ball to fall randomly with some bounce or collision.

To be precise I wish to have the kind of animation such as that obtained in the iPhone game falling balls...where the balls fall and still bounce off.

Thanks in advance for your help
CHEERS!!

```
***The .h file***

@interface TestBallsViewController : UIViewController {

  IBOutlet UIImageView *ball;

 CGPoint ballMovement;

 double size;
 double speed;

}


@property(nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *ball;


- (void)initializeTimer;


- (void)animateBall:(NSTimer *)theTimer;



**The .m file**

@implementation TestBallsViewController

@synthesize ball;


- (void)dealloc {

 [ball release];

    [super dealloc];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 ballMovement = CGPointMake(2,2);  
 [self initializeTimer];

}



- (void)initializeTimer
 { 
  float theInterval = 0.3;

  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:theInterval target:self

                   selector:@selector(animateBall:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}



- (void)animateBall:(NSTimer *)theTimer

 {
  ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x+ballMovement.x, 
                                                       ball.center.y+ballMovement.y);


     int startX =arc4random()%100;
                   int endX = arc4random()%320; 
     ball.frame= CGRectMake(startX, -100, 15.0 * size, 15 * size);
                   ball.frame = CGRectMake(endX, 480, 15.0 * size, 15.0 * size);



  if(ball.center.x > 300 || ball.center.x < 20) ballMovement.x = 
                                                                     - ballMovement.x;
  if(ball.center.y > 440 || ball.center.y < 40) ballMovement.y =
                                                                     - ballMovement.y;

 }
```

Comment: What is the point of the random content in the middle? It moves the ball to the point (random,-100) with a size of 15*size x 15*size, then immediately moves it to (random,480) with the same size. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: The random content in the middle is supposed to be the start point or where the image starts(startX) on the screen(-100) and it is supposed to end(endX) at(480) i.e the bottom of the screen on the y axis. What I am trying to do is get one image to fall from the top of the screen and disappear at the bottom. The images are created from just one image and  at any random position on the  x axis of the iPhone screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)animateBall:(NSTimer *)theTimer

 {
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x+ballMovement.x, 
                                                       ball.center.y+ballMovement.y);


     int startX =arc4random()%100;
                   int endX = arc4random()%320; 
     ball.frame= CGRectMake(startX, -100, 15.0 * size, 15 * size);
                   ball.frame = CGRectMake(endX, 480, 15.0 * size, 15.0 * size);



  if(ball.center.x > 300 || ball.center.x < 20) ballMovement.x = 
                                                                     - ballMovement.x;
  if(ball.center.y > 440 || ball.center.y < 40) ballMovement.y =
                                                                     - ballMovement.y;
  [UIView commitAnimations];

 }
```

Comment: Crystal Skull thanks a million for editing the code...I can see the image now on screen but it still has not given me what I want. Cheers!